# VLOOKUP formula cannot read dataset generated by another formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheets and the VLOOKUP formula within it. Why does the following formula return a 0?

Columns C2:Q150 are generated from a formula and number's pulled from other sheets. Columns U4:U18 are generated by using the LARGE function (to find max in a sorted manner)

[image]

Comment: I'll give an Excel comment (seeing you tagged this Excel even though it isn't Excel) but VLOOKUP requires the lookup column of the table (C2:C150) to be sorted if you use TRUE as the fourth parameter.  Google Sheets probably does the same.  Are you sure you aren't trying to lookup U4 in column A?

Comment: I am certain that I am not looking up U4 in column A. I apologize for tagging "Excel" however I figured most experts in formula writing and VBA would be the only people who could answer my question. Please use this link to get an idea of how this formula arranges parameters. Thank you for looking into this!

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) try this in V4,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$20)/(C$2:Q$20=U4), COUNTIF(U$4:U4, U4)))
```

Fill down as appropriate.

[image]

In [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) this translates to,

```
=index(A:A, small(if(C$2:Q$20=U4, row($2:$20)), countif(U$4:U4, U4)))
```

[image]

Comment: So Google Sheets doesn't have AGGREGATE function. I tried to break down your formal...would this be its equivalent?

=INDEX(A:A, SMALL(ROW($2:$20)/(C$2:Q$20=U4), COUNTIF(U$4:U4, U4)))

Comment: Lol, I thought that was clarified by user @YowE3K. Sorry. I have the solution, just had to add a TOTAL column and then used the majority of your formula to get it to work. Thank you for your help. Please don't get angry. You helped me a lot though, just saying this kind of attitude isn't appreciated and makes it very difficult to respect people.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation you posted, Google Sheet's `VLOOKUP` function works in the same way as Excel's.

So you are looking in the range $C$2:$C$150 (the first column of your table, which you specified as $C$2:$Q$150) to find the last value in that column that is less than or equal to your 36, i.e. the value in cell U4, and then returning the value in the first column of your $C$2:$Q$150 range on the found cell's row.

If the last cell in column C contains a zero, the answer will be 0.

Re the fourth parameter (which you are setting to `TRUE`), the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) says in its Notes:

> If `is_sorted` is set to `TRUE` or omitted, and the first column of the **range** is not in sorted order, an incorrect **value** might be returned. If `VLOOKUP` doesn’t appear to be giving correct results, check that the last **argument** is set to FALSE. If the data is sorted and you need to optimize for performance, set it to TRUE. In most cases it should be set to FALSE.

Comment: Thanks. So I just read what you mentioned. However, changing the formula to the following returns 36 =VLOOKUP(U4,$E$2:$E$150,1,FALSE). I am trying to get it to return 8, am I still doing something incorrectly?

Comment: You need index with aggregate returning the row match from multiple columns.

Comment: @Tigerjz32 As Jeeped says, VLOOKUP is not the right formula to use if you aren't trying to lookup a search item in a column and then return a value from a column to the right of it.  You need to start using INDEX and MATCH, etc.  If you can't get those formulas to work for you, I would suggest you raise a question stating what you are trying to do, and ask for assistance for those.  (But please do not tag as [vba], as you are not looking for a VBA solution.)

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.